# Como saber se o Web Service do app está fora do ar?

Tags: ios, web-service, objective-c, multithreading, tempo-de-resposta

Cenário: O app consome dados de um web service, para que o app não fique "travado" eu adicionei a tarefa de download dos dados em uma trhead secundária, conforme o seguinte código:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
  //realize aqui o trabalho em background
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
       //quando as operações em background forem concluídas, execute aqui o código na thread principal para atualização da tela, caso necessário
        });
    });
```

Porém, quando o web service está fora do ar, o app fica esperando a resposta do servidor, e depois de um tempo sem a resposta, o iOS encerra meu app.

Gostaria de saber se existe um Design Pattern para este tipo de situação, onde possamos controlar o tempo que o app ficará esperando resposta do servidor, e informar ao iOS para que encerre o processo de solicitação de dados sem ter que encerrar o app!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar requisições ao web service, a biblioteca mais utilizada é AFNetworking. Com ela é fácil tratar situações na qual a requisição falha, seja por problemas na conexão ou no servidor. A biblioteca já se encarrega de realizar as operações em background, gerenciar múltiplas requisições, dentre outras coisas.

Para utilizá-la, adicione ao Podfile `pod "AFNetworking"`. Caso ainda não utilize Cocoapods leia o [link](http://blog.caelum.com.br/cocoapods-o-gerenciador-de-dependencias-no-ios/).

Cada requisição terá sempre um bloco de sucesso, chamado se a requisição completar com sucesso, e um bloco de erro, chamado quando a requisição falhar (por exemplo devido a um timeout na operação). Exemplo:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Mas eu consigo determinar o tempo de espera do lado cliente? Tipo determinar que o tempo da requisição ser completa com sucesso deve ser de pelo menos 30 segundos e depois enviar um UIAlert para o usuário que a conexão com o web service não foi possível?

Comment: Sim, você consegue alterar o tempo de timeout. Exemplo:    manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 120;
O valor padrão é 60 segundos. Isto é, se a requisição não completar em 60 segundos, falhará. Para notificar o usuário sobre o erro, é só mostrar o alerta no bloco de erro.

Comment: Obrigado novamente @RafaelLeao Vou testar e ja digo se funcionou!

Comment: Ola! @RafaelLeao tentei usar este exemplo mas me retornou um erro sem baixar nenhum dado. Poderiamos conversar usando skype ou o Chat do stackoverflow? Meu Skype> tiagofly@outlook.com

Obrigado!

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema... tinha que adicionar um código nos arquivo AFURLResponseSerialization.m na linha 215: ,@"text/html",nil]; No seguinte método  self.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html",nil];

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Estou com outra dúvida pq não uso muito o AFNetworking, mas vou passar a usá-lo da qui por diante, vou postar a pergunta, se vc puder responder já agradeço adiantado! rs

Link para outra questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39332/como-enviar-dados-para-web-service-usando-afnetworking