# Como enviar dados para web service usando AFNetworking?

Tags: json, ios, web-service, objective-c, afnetworking

Eu tenho um formulario que deve ser preenchido no aplicativo e enviado ao web service para cadastrar um novo usuário.

Como poderia enviar estes dados para o web service usando AFNetworking 2.0?

Tentei usar o código abaixo, mas retornou um erro:

```
NSDictionary *params =      @{@"id" : idCadastro.text,
                             @"nome" : nomeCadastro.text,
                             @"email" : emailCadastro.text,
                             @"cidade" : localidadeCadastro.text,
                             @"passe" : senhaCadastro.text
                                                         };
    NSString* HOST_URL = @"http://10.1.1.6/advphp/cad_adv_0.php?";


    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [operationManager POST: HOST_URL parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){

        // Enter what happens here if successsful.
        NSLog(@"Cadastrado");

    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){

        // Enter what happens here if failure happens

        NSLog(@"Não Cadastrado. Erro:\n%@",error);
    }
     ];
```

E abaixo a mensagem de erro que aparece:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or
>   object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7969de10
>   {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and
>   option to allow fragments not set.}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok consegui fazer isso sem usar o parameters ou ter que converter o conteúdo para JSON.

Fiz o seguinte, criei uma `URL` completa, e passei para `URLString`: diretamente!

```
NSMutableString* urlStrin = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://10.1.1.6/advphp/cadastrar.php?id=%@&nome=%@&email=...%@",idCadastro.text, nomeCadastro.text, emailCadastro.text, localidadeCadastro.text, senhaCadastro.text];


AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager GET:urlStrin parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
// do whatever you'd like here; for example, if you want to convert
// it to a string and log it, you might do something like:

NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", string);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro indica que o json enviado pelo servidor contém fragmentos, que não são suportados pelo parser por default. Para solucionar o problema, inclua este código após a inicialização da instância de AFHTTPRequestOperationManager:

```
AFJSONResponseSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[serializer setReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
[operationManager setResponseSerializer:serializer];
```

Comment: Bom Rafael recebi o seguinte erro:

`Error Domain=NSCo coaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x7babefa0 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}`

Comment: Acredito que possa ser o servidor, pois no arquivo PHP chamado, eu estou usando $var = $_GET("id")... para receber os dados. Será que pode ser isso?

Comment: Engraçado, o app da esse erro mas cadastra os dados corretamente no banco! Mas preciso resolver este problema, pois preciso do recurso de SUCCESS ou FAILURE para chamar a próxima tela ou voltar para a anterior :/